# How to connect Azure blob storage through website MVC4

Tags: azure, web, blob

I develop a website on Windows Azure, MVC4. I try to upload and get photos from blobs. 
My related code (that I got from other examples on web):

var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnection"].ConnectionString);

```
        var blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("abc");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);
```

My related web.config code:

```
<add name="StorageConnection" connectionString="DefaultEndPointsProtocol=https;AccountName=abc;AccountKey=*******"/>
```

When I run I got a format exception. Please note that it is web site.

As per some posts, when I put my connection string to app.config, no solution.

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: I found a small typo in web.config code: "AccountNam=abc;". It should be "AccountName=abc;" [missing :"e" in AccountNam]. Could that be the reason?

Comment: No, I made a copy-paste mistake while posting. I correct it.

Comment: OK. Just wanted to make sure of that because I got a format exception because of that:). Where exactly in your code are you getting the exception?

Comment: I am getting the exception at this line: var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnection"].ConnectionString);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall not use `connectionStrings` section to store Azure Storage Connection string!
Use `appSettings` instead and you will have no issues. It is confusion that the Storage credentials is also named "Connection string", but it has nothing to do with the `connectionStrings` section in your configuration file. `connectionStrings` section is intended solely for use DataBase connection strings.